# Android: Search data and Update data

Tags: java, android

I'm a student and new to android programming and Sqlite. I've been working with my project which is the android Quiz. My only problem is on how to update the data. Before the user can update the data he/she will first search the ID of the data and the data will be loaded to the EditText. Then when I click the Button Update their is nothing change with my data. There is no error in the logcat.Please check my code. Help me Please Thank you so much..

**My DatabaseHelper class:**

```
public void updateData(int id, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase )
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_QUESTION, new_question);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER1, new_ans1);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER2, new_ans2);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER3, new_ans3);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER4, new_ans4);


        sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID +"="+id, null);


    }
```

**My Update Class:**

```
 EditText Search_Id, New_Question, New_Ans1, New_Ans2, New_Ans3, New_Ans4;
DatabaseHelper helper;
String SearchID, NewId, NewQuestion, NewAns1, NewAns2, NewAns3, NewAns4;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
TextView title_text;
Button updateButton;
int id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_contact);
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Search_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_search);
    New_Question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_question);
    New_Ans1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans1);
    New_Ans2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans2);
    New_Ans3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans3);
    New_Ans4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans4);
    title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    New_Question.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    New_Ans4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    New_Ans3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    New_Ans2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    New_Ans1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    title_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    updateButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}

public void searchContact(View view) {

    SearchID = Search_Id.getText().toString();
    sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = helper.getData(SearchID, sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        NewQuestion = cursor.getString(0);
        NewAns1 = cursor.getString(1);
        NewAns2 = cursor.getString(2);
        NewAns3 = cursor.getString(3);
        NewAns4 = cursor.getString(4);
        NewId = SearchID;

        New_Question.setText(NewQuestion);
        New_Ans1.setText(NewAns1);
        New_Ans2.setText(NewAns2);
        New_Ans3.setText(NewAns3);
        New_Ans4.setText(NewAns4);
        New_Ans4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Ans3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Ans2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Ans1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        New_Question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        title_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        updateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}


public void updateData(View view)
{
    sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

    question = New_Question.getText().toString();
    ans1 = New_Ans1.getText().toString();
    ans2 = New_Ans2.getText().toString();
    ans3 = New_Ans3.getText().toString();
    ans4 = New_Ans4.getText().toString();

    helper.updateData(id,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: what ID you want to updata? 0 ?

Comment: what should i declare sir John??

Comment: you want update data which has ID 0 ?

Comment: All existing Id in the database sir, which the user will search for the Id and update the data.

Comment: Then you should move the ID to global, not declare inside `updateData` method

Comment: Sir I already declare the id in the global but its still not working..please help.

Comment: Sir, I just declare the int id in my update class. Please sir help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the int ID to  global. Between, your ID datatype is `long` or `int` ? Different datatype will produce different result. Make sure the ID datatype is same.

**You declare int ID in update class, but why you use `long` ID in update function ?**

**Edited**

1. Add this   `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Update Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in updateData()`. Click the update button and check whether toast is displaying or not.
2. Add log in

   `updateData(int id, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)`

   Add this line `Log.e("This  is ID", id);`

Comment: Where you get the id in the update class ? Does it pass from another activity ?

Comment: Sir, I get the id in the  OpenDatabasehelper public void updateData(int id, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase )

Comment: Search sir, the user will search for the id before they can update the data.

Comment: can you post your updateButton  into your question ?

Comment: Sir, public void updateData(View view) is my onclick Button sir.

Comment: add log inside the `updateData(View view)` and `updateData` . Check whether you getting the same id or not

Comment: should I change the int id into long sir??

Comment: what did the log display ?

Comment: where should I put sir?? please can you update your answer above?? thank you sir..thank you

Comment: SIr John Joe i need your help, I want to learn on how to view the data on textview and Button, or any links that is related to android quiz application.Please Sir can you give me some links?? Thank you

Comment: view data on textview ? where are the data from ? MySQL ?

Comment: Yes Sir. My study is all about android quiz Sir, and I need to display the question on the Textview and the answer on the button. Please help me Sir.

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/how-to-fetch-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android/

Comment: Sir last link on how to make a quiz..Please sir.thank you

Comment: what quiz you want to make ?

Comment: Quiz for Midwifery students Sir, I study about android because our IT research subject required 1 program to pass the subject. Sir to be honest this website is my only hope and Thank you so much Sir for helping me.

Comment: Get the question from [here](https://www.midirs.org/how-to-become-a-midwife/qualities-needed-become-midwife/) can ?

Comment: Ya, the link I just sent to you

Comment: Ok Sir.Thank you. sorry